# IE11 function not getting passed constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, internet-explorer-11, bind

On pageload i am firing a function that should open a lightbox. In Chrome, FF, Opera, Edge and Safari everything works as it intented. In IE11 however it is not. I am not getting a warning or error in the console so I have no clue what I am doing wrong here.

I stripped the code below to the essential. In Chrome (and other browsers) the console log goes from 1 to 3 to 2. In IE11 i am only getting 1 and I have no idea why it doesn't go to 3 or 2. I thought it had something to do with bind(), but that seems to be supported.

I have to admit I am pretty new with constructors, prototypes and bind.

```
constructor(el) {
        this.$el = $(el);
        console.log('1');
        this.getLocation = getLocation.bind(this);
        this.loadLB();
        console.log('2');

    }

    loadLB() {
        const url = new URL(window.location.href);
        console.log('3');
        this.getLocation('url');  
    }
```

Comment: Warning! `const` in IE is an alias for `var`, its scope is not limited to the block it was declared in. Though this doesn't have an affect on your current code, it's good to know. I'm amazed if there's no error messages in IE, as `URL` constructor is not supported. Are you sure the error messages are not filtered out of your IE console?

Comment: Thanks Teemu, you seem to have solved it. I didn't suspect the URL constructor, but it was the problem... I was digging to deep. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to solve it with Teemu's answer, but your clarifiy's it as well. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [ConstructorMethod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor#Browser_compatibility)? It's also not supported by IE. I don't know if you have used some polyfills to make it work in IE 11.

Besides, IE doesn't support [URL() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Browser_compatibility). You can add this polyfill to make `URL()` work in IE 11:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

[image]